# TypeScript `array` that contains all possible values of a given `type`?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I am updating an open-source typescript module that allows you to work with all of the common vendors.  I need to have an array `vendors` that has all of the vendors as the `Vendor` type.  Is there a way to have the same effect from the code, but not have to repeat all of the vendors twice?

```
type Vendor =
  | "ah"
  | "apple"
  | "atsc"
  | "epub"
  | "hp"
  | "khtml"
  | "moz"
  | "ms"
  | "o"
  | "rim"
  | "ro"
  | "tc"
  | "wap"
  | "webkit"
  | "xv";

const vendors: Vendor[] = [
  "ah",
  "apple",
  "atsc",
  "epub",
  "hp",
  "khtml",
  "moz",
  "ms",
  "o",
  "rim",
  "ro",
  "tc",
  "wap",
  "webkit",
  "xv",
];
```

Please don't tell me to just add the `string[]` type to the `vendors` array because I need to use the `Vendor` type in other places within the code.

Thanks for your help and sorry that I am a typescript noob ;)

Comment: @VLAZ yes, but there probably isn't a way to set `vendors` to the type of `Vendor[]`, right?

Comment: Ok, I'll just set the type of `vendors` to `string[]` and do typechecks whenever I use it.

Comment: And should that matter? `Vendor` is already an alias to `"ah" | "apple" | "atsc"` etc. The type of `vendors` would be *exactly* that. You can always just declare it as `const vendorsArr = [ "ah", "apple", "atsc", /* ... */ ] as const;` and then do `type Vendor = typeof vendorsArr[number];` followed by `const vendors: Vendor[] = vendorsArr` or something along those lines.

Comment: lol yea I just thought of that.  Thanks for your help!